# Magento does not set cookie on product/category page

Tags: php, magento, caching, cookies, nginx

So here is the issue, Magento doesn't seem to set-cookie on product/category page.

It doesn't show any cart items or customer login information on product page, however all the items appear fine on home page and rest of the pages on site.

I checked headers for two of the pages.

Here is the product page:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: nginx/1.8.1
>   Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 05:01:57 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   X-Cacheable: NO:Cache-Control=no-cache
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   X-Served-From-Cache: Yes

Here is the home page headers (which is working fine)

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: nginx/1.8.1
>   Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 05:02:12 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>   Set-Cookie: frontend=n7m2mbnoo861h84r9ma40of221; expires=Wed, 16-Mar-2016 05:02:12 GMT; path=/store/; domain=-----; HttpOnly
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   X-Cacheable: NO:Cache-Control=no-cache
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   X-Served-From-Cache: Yes

Any idea what's happening? 
I have tried increasing cookie lifetime to 86400
and cookie path to `/store/` and cookie domain to (www.mydomain.com)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out issue was misconfiguration of varnish on server. It was serving cached pages. Solution: Restarted varnish.